# How can i find the values that are not names in a pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, neural-network

I'm working with a dataframe of names from the databases of my company. My current job is to find if some of these values, with in total are more than 3 million, are not names. If they were wrongly registrated, if the softwares of clients registered some strange values of error, etc.
Is there a neural network alghoritm or other mechanism that i can use to find that?

[Here are some values of the column. I want to see every value that are kind of different from these[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SifUD.png)

I tried to see by the number of letters of strings, but it was useless.

Answer (score 0):

Try to post some code of your tries so other can help you

Comment: I think this is more of a comment rather than answer.